# Is it legal to publish information about the server on a shared hosting webspace?

Tags: website

I have a shared hosting webspace on a linux server.
I am showing the uptime of the server on my website, because it's interesting to see...

I am now questioning if it's is legal to publish any information about the server to the public?

For example:

- the files on the server
- hardware information (cpu temperature, free disk space, ...)
- software running on it (displaying version information could be a security risk)
- other users on the server
- content of configuration files

Comment: You can see files on the server that are not your own files? If so you may want to switch to a less interesting provider. 

Comment: If you have that much access to your server, I would definitely look elsewhere for hosting. There is no way you should be able to see things like directories outside of your /home, as well as logged in users and configuration files. I think the "legality" of posting such information may very well depend on where the server is located and where you are located, as it is, this is unanswerable in a legal context.

Comment: What would make it illegal? Are the files protected under some law?

Comment: I have my webspace at one of the biggest providers on the web. I can for example see and read configuration files in /etc using php. But that's normal. It was like that on all my webspaces.

Comment: Also you could easily violate the terms of service.

Answer (score 1):

While this might be unwise, I can see no reason why it would be illegal unless your server is, for example, a part of the national security IT infrastructure, or belongs to a law firm, or some other entity that owes the highest degree of confidentiality.

Comment: I thought it was a crime in many places to access computer systems without authorisation, even if the security is no good. Would this apply here?

Comment: @StefanoPalazzo The question seemed to imply that the access was authorized. If that is not the case, the question needs to clarify that fact.